# ADO application in which the values in a single column get added and displayed in a textbox

Tags: c#, aspxgridview

I am developing an ADO application in which the values in the single column get added and are displayed in a textbox.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 6)
        label13.Text = CellSum().ToString();
}

private double CellSum()
{
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
    {
        int d = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString());
        sum += d;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

It's not working, it's showing an error for me.

Comment: What's the error mate?

Comment: I have cleared the error now... but the thing is the values are not adding bro.

Comment: In the CellValueChanged you have ColumnIndex == 6 but you are summing Cells[5]

Comment: yeah I changed it to cells[6] but still its not working

Comment: on which line you are getting error?

Comment: I have cleared all the errors its not showing any error for me now. but the code is not working, its not displaying the added values bro

Comment: dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString() giving you the correct values that can be converted to int ?

Comment: If you are getting the sum and problem is in display then check visibility of label13

Comment: dude I will explain you clearly. I have a column named amount. I want to add all the values in that column and display it in a label.

Comment: Check that foreground and background colour of label are not the same! Also put break point in CellSum and check that it is being called

Comment: Is the Amount column editable?

Comment: yeah bro. its an editable column only

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of your list view mate?